# Behavior flow Structure in Google analytics - Traffic flow

Tags: google-analytics

The Behavior flow chart :

[image]

The first node (white one) is the dimension node which is the entry point for the other pages in the site. The green nodes are the page nodes or starting pages.  Why is the dimension node name and the corresponding green node has the same name Login. how is the traffic is flowing into the same page again.(from dimension node to starting page)
Please help me to understand.

Answer (score 1):

White node is not a fist page of flow. It's something like source. You can change this dimension to other, for example to `Campaign` or `Service Provider`. 
The first step (page) of flow is a green node, you can see title "Starting pages" above green node.